# jQuery Draggable + Sortable - How to change the sortable items?

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I have a sortable list of videos initialised with the option:

```
items: '.videoBox:not(.isFirst, .isLast)',
```

The first and last videos are not sortable, neither are they draggable in any way - this is great!

This is connected to another draggable list of videos using the `connectToSortable` option. Some of the videos I want to be able to drag in between the `isLast` and `isFirst` videos (of which there are many) so for those I need these items sortable again, so I use:

```
start: function(event, ui) {
  if (// my test //)
  {
      $('#timeline').sortable('option', 'items', '.videoBox');
  }
},
```

This allows me to drag and drop amongst the items that were previously not sortable - great!

Now I want to revert the sortable to the initial set up once the drag has finished, so I put this in the draggable init:

```
stop: function() {
  if (// my test //)
  {
    $('#timeline').sortable('option', 'items', '.videoBox:not(.isFirst, .isLast)');
    $('#timeline').sortable('refresh');
    $('#timeline .videoBox.isLast, #timeline .videoBox.isFirst').draggable('destroy');
  }
},
```

This works great IF the draggable is not dropped into #timeline. However if it is dropped into `#timeline` then this callback does not seem to be called(?). I have added the exact same code into the sortable events: `stop`, `update` and `deactivate`, and while I can see that these callbacks are getting fired, the `isFirst` and `isLast` videos are still draggable.

However they are not sortable - so I think the problem lies with the `.draggable('destroy')` bit... Any ideas/suggestions?

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havent been able to fix or even identify the cause of the problem above. I have however found a workaround that seems fairly robust.

In the `stop` callback of the `sortable` init:

```
stop: function() {
    $('#timeline').sortable('option', 'items', '.videoBox:not(.isFirst, .isLast)');
    opts = $('#timeline').sortable('option');
    $('#timeline').sortable('destroy');
    $('#timeline').sortable(opts);
}
```

The first line sets the items option as I have been doing before. Then I save the `sortable` init options to a variable, destroy the `sortable` behaviour and reinitialise it with the correct options. This does what I want now - i destroys the draggable on the `isFirst` and `isLast` items). I have left the `stop` callback exactly as above in the `draggable` callback which is required for the case when the drag does not end up over the sortable.

Seems like a bit of a sledgehammer approach but struggling to find a nicer method. Be interested to know if anyone has any other suggestions though.

Tom